# Windows command processor: Output redirection mechanics

Tags: cmd, overwrite, io-redirection

With windows' cmd.exe, when you run a command like

```
output.exe > out.txt
```

with an existing, non-empty file 'out.txt' what actually happens?

Is a new 'out.txt' created while the old one is deleted in 'rm out.txt' fashion?
I assume it doesn't literally write over the old 'out.txt', because that seems possibly dangerous.

P.S. *Could* you use cmd.exe commands to write over the old file's data specifically?

i.e.

```
>type out.txt
This is a sentence.  
>strangeEchoes That > out.text
>type out.txt
That is a sentence.
```

P.P.S

Information is always welcome, the more and longer-winded the better =)

P.P.P.S.

Sorry if I'm bad at searching for answers / asking questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based off a [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) trace, when `echo text > filename.txt` is ran, a call is made to `CreateFile` with the `dwCreationDisposition` flag set to `CREATE_ALWAYS`, which

> Creates a new file, always.
>
> If the specified file exists and is writable, the function overwrites
>   the file, the function succeeds, and last-error code is set to
>   ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS (183).
>
> If the specified file does not exist and is a valid path, a new file
>   is created, the function succeeds, and the last-error code is set to
>   zero.

`echo demo2 >> filename.txt`, on the otherhand, calls `CreateFile` with `CREATE_NEW` and opens the existing file.  The process then gets the end of the file, reads one byte from the end and starts writing thereafter.  I would guess it is looking for a `^Z` character at the end which it needs to overwrite when it reads the last character, but that is just a guess.

Answer (score 0):

append the output to an existing file:

```
>>out.txt output.exe
```